# Why is the email sent containing HTML code rather than in HTML form?

Tags: html, asp.net, email

I am trying to send an outlook email as follows,I don't see any errors or exceptions but when the email comes out its still in HTML code as shown below?what am I missing?

```
    public object SendBuildAnnouncementEmail(string softwareProductBuildID)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("fromname@yourmail.com", "toname@yourmail.com");
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Port = 25;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Host = "smtphost.company.com";
            mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
            //mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
            mail.Body = "";
            var output = GetBuildAnnounceDetails(softwareProductBuildID);
            foreach (var item in output)
            {
                mail.Body += "<html>";
                mail.Body += "<p>" + item.SP + "</p>";
                mail.Body += "<p>" + item.CreatedDate + "</p>";
                mail.Body += "<p>" + item.AnnouncedDate + "</p>";
                mail.Body += "<p>" + item.AnnouncedBy + "</p>";
                mail.Body += "</html>";
            }
            //client.Send(mail);
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

HTML code:-

```
<html><p>spname</p><p>4/8/2017 5:24:37 PM</p><p>4/8/2017 5:43:34 PM</p><p>name</p></html>
```

Comment: Try adding `mail.IsBodyHtml = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send HTML formatted emails, add

```cs
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

to your code. ( Before `client.Send(mail);` )

Comment: There is none. While it's always good to include doctypes, the `<html>` is not necessarily needed in HTML Mails.